# Is it possible to know when was the last update of a dynamic (PHP/ASP) web page content?

Tags: updates, webpage, date

**Update:** the question was not clear enough....

I have found a bookmarklet that give me the date of a web page last update:

```
javascript:alert(document.lastModified)
```

But it's not very effective because it only works for plain old html.

Is there a clever way to get the date of the last **content** update (without having tracked it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a user, unless the web itself gives you that information you have no way of correctly getting that information from a dynamically generated page. Unless you keep track of that website every X time and compare the current version with the last copy, but that's either getting into coding or using a software to keep track of the site for you.

Answer (score 1):

You want to know the last time the template was updated? Because the last update of a dynamic page is by definition the last time it was requested.

Comment: I was not clear enough, question updated...

Comment: Dynamic content comes out of a database, so I'm pretty sure that, barring johnnyArt's suggestion, the answer to your question is no.

Answer (score 1):

How about google reader (which tracks changes and makes an rss feed for sites without it) and a rss feed reader?

Answer (score 0):

You can check browser history. At least in Firefox for sure.

Comment: I could check my last visit in firefox, not when the web page was updated...